# Read a text file (containing characters) & store it in a 2D array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I want to read a text file (containing characters) and store them in an array (preferably String or char array) in java.

I have the following file:

```
TIRQHHVZZRDAPOBVPSUJIODEZMYPYNGQIODWBXKCTOTRGZZEMP
MLWLOPBIEWVOGGODRFVRZNATTNOYMMQGAWLYYEPZTZLKDZNNOV
YQBSITHGIEQLQOILXJZRMZOAZPUKBBHEZEWRIOXKQITJQYJWYA
WRMHAKAEDTERKFXPNQSHSUOOTCCQDNNSTUNICGHKPSAEBVZCEK
GLHKDMIXJVBGKGDURNOKKDTUVYKKFJIPUCCIKQLUTGXUBVDDWE
IMLOXJTMXFBTOPIHAXCMLDSVOYKJVKPNITIFNHLSBUSKOQYEVE
FIMTDKSLPLOGDPSQNRYKNZWESINHKUAUAJNLQRBESGDIJAZXCZ
XPASOKPBHLESOVQNWHWCJQVKQPAVQWORDJLDEQTZLWVRVCECQE
VSRWFOURTEENPCSZYKJXKDSYMZYFBNNUMKPTPYUYESFMJPQWAX
OFTMDZFHVAGAXAVIMCDFFTYTMBZJXGSTHTWBFKOFMCPMYSDBHW
ZTTDOSGXMRHCWWJZTGRVYZBYAUWGADVBMNPGXISWWQOGYCOJQI
WKCLDAPLTYUACEWYDPFKENVEBQUCRILMZMOTYTZASQZHDKJCUD
YLNPTATVKWKQCKXDOLOTTINLECNSFQAYWXKVGQPUTOCTQRHPLD
KVIDVLMOLCWQOCPIIUMEFEKVLBRJBOOANJVAGENXLDJSZHQEZO
WVMXYCURWDEWZMYQWNDJEWSAEGKXUJSNVDQNYPLGASVJPJTTTK
QYHETHVZXHXLXOFLOYEERHTRVUZUGTTVXSDXGFPLFNJKYEGITB
EOEALPUNSRSAVAMRFKADVNLUEKWPHINLQIRFADMPHBLRABBDYD
WJCFVKAJXQAJGGFTVMHEHEIQNOQVNYCKBETIDJFWGAFHETDFLW
UHJLWHNZRBYPBFUZLDYZRHDZRWUHIOTNXGHTJWUPOWMOLUAJPN
UQEVRGNDRVLCDCZVMUJKXEJESRJWCWPHLSFJRSNZHSIQFCXJCA
ADLEPOVWXCMSZNDJCDLZXSEXBILSTACOZEIKEPWXJROWVWZEKO
ENIUTYQLIPJCGDICMKLBFYYCLAYAGETKJVVROTFUOXWKKRZPQB
WESALMTALHTRUPJDTEIMXBGBYBQVCPHSDEEZJWSJPVQFQBDYYB
EEOUDWUQBQCCRXTSPOEFWAOFPATICKATVNHVGMJVLDJRXAVHXG
RTWDJHUOTLSIKAOEGFTWREHWVOYEVNHNOUENUJYBJPSDMDMLCN
KRDXWECKGIXTRQDSQMYREUTUTQSIBOIQEZDTMKSGCWJJVRQVSY
MIGDSUXFWBDUVPRHYLUQIVMLFYFRVOENPUZTIWBLODVAFNKEFF
AHIOOZHGDARPHSMSLQWAGWUKSACUZQZZERYGRPYXHLXSWYXWUP
RTOCFOMDMMLTRQHYUPIJHDZPGFYZLYGPHTTFSEVENTEENLJOUE
JAQULXRCFGYACYOKILEATGLRQJORZEFNPCEIFIEOJGWJFIFBJU
ABWTYDWZDLNHITFALZHMEICJTIQMCMPELZYEOJHTSOSOLDKCIH
KZELECUWWFKZWWVEFOUREFHDBQLODRKXNQYZNCECIUTXEHUZIF
TUWDRQQXZSGGBEPOUCRDNBHIISRGOQPDLOFPPDJPXKNHSSSBWK
QJUTINZTCTEXCNHEUUTLUWAFXNVHWYQNWTJKPXTZTVJSWTFJYX
ESXMYTZXQNQLNTTTLWURFPRZJONBUJZNMOCAXEXJEXRTHUAZBP
HEWRYQKJHTWFBYLVXAWRLZUCHBNECQAQEUWVTMVUEUAEZGOLVJ
KJJCWQPEKOMYBUQASGHPTBLDAIXGZHSSCELCGQFCNFAQPKALHQ
IFLROSXWZSGPBTCZBGMRVTHCIJLDLBIRFDTNXBYWQQOFXENAAZ
IWFOWBGUXPVMBXVVMKIUCTZTQKECNSJLNVKFGKZCPOEGDEZWSW
GBNMJKZMEETSFTWTCNOHKFAPEXVRIMJVADKOIAMTASKAHGQKGL
TIXKEOHXLBLFQQGXNCWRYWLNYPLKADPCILWKQFHXCKXSFTWESE
YPZRVDVSZYSSVHEQRQOYUUTAAQEZFBQTCRVTLXVJWHWQSKNJUD
WAZETCDRIUDDQYOKPMFYIVCQJUWVPTYWXKIRJJBEOAXJUAZUSI
GYSWSAWRLXIFICREJUESOBJBYCTSTAXMMMIUVMDTJMZQBUAGTX
XIELYZYXIEDZUULIAAMZMRTEVCUDQRQOYEXPDQUZHCUCOFBUJH
KJYUWVRLIRFPJJTWWHHEUQYZKJBNAUEUOFOSNJQPVGBCJDAZVN
NYMKHEVUWTSONMYOLSSOYHYLHCZJBTLEVSOYMCAYDALDYSMYZJ
BNKEQXFQNLEUBLTEJPZXCHYSRLHYVCKGLHTJBTJUNNHCXEIXNW
VUYPYWZIEVXDRTCMJZQZENNWQPGCQODHEGXQCNJRVYZUSTPYYQ
EAVVSGHIROLJFPRAFPBJTAWYYTLUTTYNJPZBVLSJUNYBFHEPED
```

I'm using the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
public class A3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        FileReader f = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Dell\\Desktop\\COSC600\\sampleinp.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(f);

        String ar[][] = new String [50][50];

        for(int i=0;i<ar.length;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<ar.length;j++) {
                String s = br.readLine();
                ar[i][j] = s.split(" ");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

PS: Please ignore the imports & code errors. This is only partial code.

Any help will be much appreciated!

expected output: in a 2-D array

```
T I R Q H H V Z Z R D A P O B .........P
M L W L O P B I E W V O G G O .........V
Y Q S I T H G I E Q O .................A
```

Comment: what error did you get? where are spaces in your text?

Comment: @NabinBhandari  . Thank you for your time:

Error: when I try to do, ar[i][j] = s. split(" ") ; it complains that "can not converted from string to charecter array".

I have realized that I have to include spaces, and I did, but I have copied from a different file in which the charecters are not spaced. My bad.

Comment: why you want to store it in 2D array? @AmithAdiraju

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, but my assignment states that I have to take those values in an array. I have to  perform "Needle in a Haystack" sort of search on this array with another array. So I have to take it a 2D array. @AshokBala

Comment: string.split will always return one Dimensional array. Here you want to use  " " as needle right?  @AmithAdiraju

Comment: My needle is a totally different input file. It has some words in it, say array2. I have to search for the words of array2 in this array and print the relevant position of that word. @AshokBala

Answer (score 0):

The function `split()` returns array of `String`, not `String`. Try the following code:

```
for(int i=0;i<ar.length;i++) {
    String s = br.readLine();
    ar[i] = s.split(" ");
}
```

Comment: how do i store this into a 2-D array ?

Comment: `ar` is a 2D array.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `split("")`?

Comment: Splitting with a blank String? Only if Array of individual character is required.  The OP hasn't made it clear.

Comment: but isn't ar[i] a single dimension array from the way we are storing the values in it? Correct me if im wrong, but as far as I know , "ar[i] = s.split(" ") " will store all the text in a huge single line ( horrizontal row). @NabinBhandari

Comment: @AmithAdiraju, your question is unclear, please provide your sample input file and sample output.

Answer (score 0):

Man do you really need to use an array? I would do something like this to read the file

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

 public class A3 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    FileReader f = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Dell\\Desktop\\COSC600\\sampleinp.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(f);

    List<String[]> words = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    line = br.readLine();
    while(line != null){

    words.add(line.split(""));
    line = br.readLine();   

}}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, but my assignment states that I have to take those values in an array. I have later perform "Needle in a Haystack" sort of search on this array with another array. So I haveto take it a 2D array.